# What are the possible products in allylic bromination of 3-methylcyclopentene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, radicals

> Bromination of an alkene by *N*-bromosuccinimide (NBS) in the presence of light or peroxide is a radical reaction and produces an allylic bromide. For the following bromination of 3-methylcyclopentene, which of the following allylic bromides would be products of the reaction?
>
> [image: Allylic bromination of 3-methylcyclopentene]

In some other reactions such as elimination, there is a tendency to form the most substituted double bond, since it is the most stable. If that were the case, then the products should be **A**, **E**, **F**, and **G**, since these are all trisubstituted alkenes (the others are disubstituted). Is that a valid consideration here, or is there a different overriding rule?

Comment: I think it should be `A,C,F,D` ,though I am not sure. I'll do some review and get back.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with A, C, and F

wondering why it cant be G or E :/ confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Alkene substitution is only really important in a couple of cases: firstly when the reaction is entirely thermodynamically controlled (e.g. aldol reactions), and secondly if the transition state in the rate-determining step contains strong double bond character (i.e. more substituted double bond = lower-energy transition state).

Neither of that is the case here. The double bond is constrained by its initial position, and cannot jump around all that much. In theory, there are $ 2 \times 2 = 4$ possible products (**A**, **C**, **D**, and **F**) because:

- the initial abstraction of a hydrogen atom can occur at two different positions, and
- the allylic radical thus formed can pick up a bromine atom at two different positions.

The mechanistic possibilities are drawn out fully below:

[image: Mechanistic possibilities]

In practice, there would likely be one product that is preferred over the others. Note the use of *resonance arrows*, $\ce{<->}$: these are *not* flipping about between the two different resonance structures. Rather, the reality is that the allylic radical is somewhere in-between the two extremes. We only draw out the two extremes here because it's a convenient way of looking at its reactivity (which is sort of a mixture of both extremes).

Answer (score 2):

Your comment shows that you are on the right track.

You have chosen **A** and **C** because they are formed when the initial allylic radical **instantaneously** reacts with $\ce{Br2}$ in the propagation step of the reaction, isn't it? (*Hint: Just say YES!*)

Now give the **allylic radicals** corresponding to **A** and **C** a bit of time, just enough to *flip the dot*.

How do these other radicals look like? There you have the other two products.

For an extra point: Which isomer of methylcyclopentene could lead to **G**?